# How to use map in flutter to solve the problem i have

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Hi I have these 2 dropdown widgets and one tag selector widget
```

```
//add drug
String drugName;
String drugForm;
List<String> drugPower=[];

//add drug list
var drugList = [];
```

```
Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 0),
           child: DropdownButtonFormField(
             value: drugName,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               labelText: 'Medicine',
               labelStyle: poppins1,
             ),
             items: ['Paracetemol', 'Ozopin']
                 .map((name) =>
                 DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('$name'), value: name))
                 .toList(),
             onChanged: (val) {
               setState(() {
                 drugName = val;
               });
             },
           ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 0),
           child: DropdownButtonFormField(
             value: drugForm,
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               labelText: 'Form',
               labelStyle: poppins1,
             ),
             items: ['Tablets', 'Pills']
                 .map((form) =>
                 DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('$form'), value: form))
                 .toList(),
             onChanged: (val) {
               setState(() {
                 drugForm = val;
               });
             },
           ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 0),
           child: Column(
             children: [
               GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {
                   showAlert(
                       ['100 mg', '200 mg', '500 mg'], drugPower,
                           (list) {
                             drugPower.clear();
                             drugPower = list;
                       });
                 },
                 child: Container(
                   width: double.infinity,
                   height: 70,
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                     top: 15,
                   ),
                   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                   child: Column(
                       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                       children: [
                         Text(
                           'Power',
                           style: poppins1,
                         ),
                         Row(
                           mainAxisAlignment:
                           MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                           crossAxisAlignment:
                           CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                           children: [
                             Text(drugPower.length > 0
                                 ? drugPower[0]
                                 : ''),
                             Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)
                           ],
                         ),
                       ]),
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       border: Border(
                           bottom:
                           BorderSide(width: 1, color: color2))),
                 ),
               ),
               SizedBox(
                 height: 10,
               ),
               Wrap(
                 children: displayChips(drugPower),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
```

below is the tag selector code as a popup dialog

```
  showAlert(List<String> tags, List<String> finalTags,
      Function(List<String>) onSelectionChanged) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Select Power'),
            content: Wrap(
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                finalTags.contains(tags[i])
                                    ? Colors.blue[400]
                                    : Colors.white)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            finalTags.contains(tags[i])
                                ? finalTags.remove(tags[i])
                                : finalTags.add(tags[i]);
                            onSelectionChanged(finalTags);
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            showAlert(tags, finalTags, (list) {

                              finalTags = list;
                            });
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          tags[i],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: drugPower.contains(tags[i])
                                  ? Colors.white
                                  : Colors.black),
                        )),
                  )
              ],
            ),
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                child: Text(
                  'save',
                  style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: color4),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: color4,
                  onPrimary: color5,
                  padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 30.0),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

now when I click the save button once the 3 widget values are selected I'm storing  the values like below

```
saveDrug() {
    var list = [
      drugName,
      drugForm,
      drugPower
    ];

    setState(() {
      drugList.add(list);
    });
  }
```

when I add one iteration of values to druglist it's working fine but when I add two or more iterations to druglist, the drugpower value is the same for all the iterations(in druglist). how can I solve this problem so that each iteration is based on my selection of drugpower tags?

below is the video link to my widget setup
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LLmE.jpg

Comment: Hi There. What do you mean by adding another iteration of values ? Do you have a save button somewhere. Try adding images to your post to make it more easier to understand

Comment: below the 3 widgets i have a button which on click calls the saveDrug() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suspect is that you have problem with references,

Change your `saveDrug` to this,

```
saveDrug() {
  setState(() {
    drugList = [
      ...drugList,
      [drugName, drugForm, drugPower]
    ];

    // After we add one drug, we dont need the old values, so just erase them
    drugName = null;
    drugForm = null;
    drugPower = [];
  });
}
```

Now, your `drugList` should be updating normally.

Here is the result after adding 3 times,

[image]

I was displaying the result in a `Column` like this, since you didn't provide code,

```
Column(
  children: drugList.map((e) => Text(e.toString())).toList(),
)
```

Comment: what does those 3 dots before druglist mean

Comment: It is the `spread` operator. Basically, it means put all the elements that are current present in `drugList` inside this new List that I am creating. Check this for more info https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue ? any other error that is coming ?

Comment: first of all thanks for the help. I'm currently away from my work computer. ill check and get back to this tomorrow

Comment: sure, do check it out.